# Add a menu to a newly created Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, menu, google-sheets-api

I am trying to add a menu to a newly created Spreadsheet using Google App Script.
I don't know if that is even possible.
Can I somehow automatically add a script to a new Spreadsheetfile where i can define the onOpen() method?
Or can I add the menu from the outside of the Spreadsheet-file, where I have created the file itself?

My code looks like this:

```
  sheetfile = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheetName);
  sheetfile = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetfile.getId());
  sheetfile = SpreadsheetApp.open(sheetfile);      
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Choose Folder", functionName: "showPicker"});
  sheetfile.addMenu("Export to JSON-file", menuEntries);
```

But this does not work.
Your help is very much appreciated! :D

Comment: Adding menus to all new documents can be done with Add Ons, which are reusable across your files. All other scripts run as single instances within the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert a script directly when creating a new spreadsheet.

The best way to get this effect is to create template spreadsheet with the necessary script (with the onOpen & your other functions) attached, then create a copy of that template sheet instead of creating a brand new sheet.

When you create the copy, the script will be carried over along with any contents in the sheet.

```
var template_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('YOUR TEMPLATE SHEET URL');
var sheetfile = template_sheet.copy(sheetName);
```